# (W10) Register application to manage phone numbers in web browsers (like skype)

Tags: c#, windows, web, registry, phone-number

I need to register my app coded in c# on (at least) Windows10, in order to make it elegible to open URLs that are phone numbers on web browsers (preferably Chrome). If i'm not wrong, skype does/did it. Anyone knows how to do it?

Best regards and thanks in advance :)

**UPDATE:** Thanks to **Oscar** for his answer.

I've tried to put this keys:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
   tel
      (Default) = "URL:tel Protocol"
      URL Protocol = ""
      DefaultIcon
         (Default) = "c:\Program Files\Test\Test.exe,1"
      shell
         open
            command
               (Default) = "C:\Program Files\Test\Test.exe" "%1"
```

When I click a phone number with this scheme ("tel:nnnnnnnnn"), both Chrome and IE open a new windown allowing me to choose what app open, but my custom app doesn't appear :(

**UPDATE 2:** Seems like is not possible to do it on W10 (see comments bellow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like is not possible on W10...

The way that the applications can set itself as default ones has changed. Now the user is who decides what app should do the action... and the app has to be on the Windows Store...

See this article for a full explanation:

http://www.tenforums.com/software-apps/21303-how-do-you-set-protocol-association-standalone-exe.html

Comment: From your article: "It works if you don't have Skype or Chrome installed. After that moment, you will not be able to change default app for tel protocol through system settings although you have these into registry for your app (this is valid for win 10, for others < win 10, it works nice)"

Comment: Yes, so in this case it's not possible :)

Answer (score 0):

It involves writing some keys to register the tel: URI as handled by your application.

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
   alert
      (Default) = "URL:Alert Protocol"
      URL Protocol = ""
      DefaultIcon
         (Default) = "alert.exe,1"
      shell
         open
            command
               (Default) = "C:\Program Files\Alert\alert.exe" "%1"
```

See this article for a full description:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx

And this one about the tel: URI

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3966